# Prisma.io + Full Text Search + PostgreSQL: Search is only working with exact match

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, prisma

I have enabled [full text search for prisma](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/full-text-search) and I would like to search the `email` field returning all entries that match.

I got the following code:

```
const data = await this.prismaService.merchant.findMany({
  where: {
    email: {
      search: '12rwqg13tr222vqfgedvqrw22@someprovider.de',
    },
  },
});
```

This is working when I enter the exact email address. However, when I try to search for a part of it, i.e. `12rwqg13tr222vqfgedvqrw22@someprovider`, I get no results.

Do I have to create indexes to accomplish this? In the docs it is mentioned that I only need indexes for PostgreSQL if I want to speed up the queries. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

apparently I was looking at the wrong feature. [`contains`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/filtering-and-sorting) is what I was looking for:

```
const res = await prisma.post.findMany({
  where: {
    author: {
      email: {
        contains: 'prisma.io',
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Edit: If you need case insensitive search, have a look at [the prisma docs for case sensitivity](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/case-sensitivity#options-for-case-insensitive-filtering)

```
const res = await prisma.post.findMany({
  where: {
    author: {
      email: {
        contains: 'prisma.io',
        mode: 'insensitive',
      },
    },
  },
})
```

This would match `Prisma.IO` as well.